# Xposed Framework removed after manual CM update?

Tags: cyanogenmod, xposed-framework

I'm currently running the official nightly of cm12.1 on my LG G3 AT&T (model d850) with the Xposed Framework installed. However, every time I manual update Cyanogenmod (as I don't have a compatible recovery for automatic installation), the Xposed Framework gets removed/disabled, forcing me to locate the downloaded framework zip file (xposed manual installation because of reasons). This is not really a big issue for me and doesn't greatly affect myself or my phone in anyway but it will be glad if someone has found a 'possible' solution for this minor bug

Comment: Pretty sure updating destroys the system partition, which Xposed is installed to. Could be wrong though.

Comment: Yeah I was thinking that too... At one point I thought the updates would just overwrite files not folders (referring to /system), unless the xposed framework modifies system files (e.g. build.prop). But idk tho...

Comment: You need to check the updater script in one of the zip files.

Comment: @jeffery-lin ah yes I found a function called 'install_overwrite'. So um...yup. That's enough said....but thanks btw!

Comment: You can add this as an answer to help others that may stumble upon this question in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Ok so this isn't a bug but in the updater script of the xposed framework, a function called **install_overwrite** is called upon several occasion and, hence the name overwrite, will replace pre-existing file in the /system folder. So in order to install the xposed framework, it's necessary to reinstall it with each update.

Comment: That's true – as Xposed replaces a part of the system's framework (one file) to "hook in and expose its interfaces" (hence the name), which an OS update again would overwrite – effectively disabling Xposed.

Answer (score 1):

This script will automatically reinstall Xposed after dirty-flashing a ROM (i.e. flashing it without wiping userdata). The linked post includes instructions to download and how to install it, and describes how it works.
https://www.reddit.com/r/xposed/comments/3u2xw9/release_xposed_addond_backup_scripts_it_keeps/

Try to search "xposed script after updating cyanogenmod" with your search engine

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. Otherwise, your answer becomes useless in case the link dies. For further hints, please see: [How do I write a good answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).